# Retrieving large data amount as datalist from Remote PC

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I have a simple HTML page that allows the user to select the amount of fields to enter information. Once the user selects a number, a Javascript onchange method is called that sends the parameter to a PHP page where data is retrieved from a database and stored in a datalist, that is dynamically appended to the HTML page.

When I access this function on the host PC, everything works perfectly. However, when I access this from a remote client, the input fields dont generate automatically.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function GetInfo(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/Return-List.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="../php/Submit.php">
            <label>Number of Items</label>
            <input type="number" name="numberofitems" onchange='GetInfo(this.value)'>
            <br/>
            <div id="items"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Go"  />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    if($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed");
    } else {
        $items = $_GET['q'];
        $fields = "";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name, desc FROM ItemTB");
        for($i=1; $i<=$items ; $i++) {
            $fields .= "<label>Input</label>
                        <input list='items' name='items[]' />
                        <datalist id='items'>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $fields .= "<option value='" . $row['name'] . " | " . $row['desc'] . "'> " . $row['desc'] . "</option>";
            }

            $fields .= "</datalist>"; 
        }
        echo $fields;
    }
?>
```

I have tried using relative and fixed locations in the JavaScript, and limiting the results to 500. Limiting the database results works, and it is important to note that the table returns upwards of 170 000 results. This seems to be the issue here.

How do I retrieve the entire dataset? Is there a way to do this more efficiently, to pack all data without lag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Efficiency" is very subjective.  There's no one-size-fits-all answer.  But I question if you actually intend to show all 170,000 results immediately?  If nothing else you might want to break the results into smaller chunks and have the javascript loop through requesting the smaller chunks.  That way the results can be displayed to the user as they arrive rather than waiting for all of them.

Comment: I think, optimally, showing perhaps 50 results at a time is more than sufficient. I am new to JavaScript though, and unsure of how I would go about doing this. Could you please assist me?

Comment: @PhilipCouling please assist me, or point me in the direction of where to look? I could really use your help